# Issues running asynchronous code in unit tests

Tags: swift, unit-testing, asynchronous

So I am having issues running asynchronous code in the unit tests of my app. I am using expectations in order to wait for the code to execute before the test completes. The asynchronous code runs through heroku in order to get the values and then should return them in the app. With this unit test, I am trying to make sure the connection through heroku is working. Here is a look at my code:

```
func test() {
    let url = "https://s.herokuapp.com/test"

    let params: [String: Any] = ["account_id": AppState.sharedInstance.user.accounttoken]

    let expectation = self.expectation(description: "Testing returning value")

    let totalBalance = ""
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print("Returned with success")
            case .failure(let error):
                let status = response.response?.statusCode
                print("Failed, status: \(status)")
                print("Here is the error: \(error)")
            }

            if let result = response.result.value {
                let balance = result as! NSDictionary
                let totalBalance = String(describing: "\(balance["Balance"]!)")
            }
            XCTAssert(totalBalance != "")
            expectation.fulfill()
    }
    waitForExpectations(timeout: 10, handler: nil)
    XCTAssert(totalBalance != "")
}
```

The reason I am confused is because I have no error getting the asynchronous code to return values in the actual app. I only have the wait time issue in unit testing. I am getting two fail errors, one for the XCTAssert not being true and one for the waitForExpectations going longer than 10 seconds. Here is some of the errors that are popping up as well if that helps find the solution:

[image: Error Messages]

Here is the error messages in text form:

> 2019-07-01 09:44:38.181971-0400 Spotbirdparking[49677:4306598] TIC TCP
>   Conn Failed [6:0x6000030b7cc0]: 3:-9816 Err(-9816) 2019-07-01
>   09:44:38.188607-0400 Spotbirdparking[49677:4306598]
>   NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9816) 2019-07-01 09:44:38.188819-0400
>   Spotbirdparking[49677:4306598] Task
>   .<1> HTTP load failed (error
>   code: -1200 [3:-9816]) 2019-07-01 09:44:38.189215-0400
>   Spotbirdparking[49677:4306623] Task
>   .<1> finished with error - code:
>   -1200 /Users/drewloughran/Desktop/SpotBird/SpotbirdparkingTests/SpotbirdparkingTests.swift:117:
>   error: -[SpotbirdparkingTests.SpotbirdparkingTests test_stripe] :
>   Asynchronous wait failed: Exceeded timeout of 10 seconds, with
>   unfulfilled expectations: "Testing stripe returning value".

I am also fairly new to swift so any help would be appreciated with this problem.

Comment: What's the reason of mentioning `XCTAssert(totalBalance != "")` twice? Also, are you sure that the task is finished before the 10 seconds timeout triggered?

Comment: The XCTAssert in the code twice was just me trying to figure out if I had it in the right place, sorry about that missed that when typing the question. And I have tried longer wait times as well but that does not seem to change the errors that I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

Drew, please check this error first. Your request is failing to load.

```
 HTTP load failed (error code: -1200 [3:-9816]) 2019-07-01 09:44:38.189215-0400 Spotbirdparking[49677:4306623] Task .<1> finished with error - code: -1200
```

Also make sure that the block you are using to fulfill the expectation is being executed. Probably it's not and that's the reason your expectation is not fulfilled and your test is failing.

Also, [from this documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Alamofire/4.0.1/) I can see that your validation intersects an automatic validation case. which is redundant.

```
 Response Validation
By default, Alamofire treats any completed request to be successful, regardless of the content of the response. Calling validate before a response handler causes an error to be generated if the response had an unacceptable status code or MIME type.

Manual Validation
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get")
    .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
    .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
    .response { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            print("Validation Successful")
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
Automatic Validation
Automatically validates status code within 200...299 range, and that the Content-Type header of the response matches the Accept header of the request, if one is provided.

Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").validate().responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success:
        print("Validation Successful")
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the help with the validation. I have a question about request is failing error. Do you think that is a unit test error specifically, because similar requests to Alamofire are working in my app?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be testing your Alamofire calls by doing actual networking. This causes you to hit the network every time you test; it is unreliable (the network can fail) and unnecessary. We know what the network does! You also do not have to test Alamofire; it isn't yours to test, and again, you know what it does. Therefore you should refactor your code for testing and *mock* the network call.